# Implement login script in wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i want to implement a register/login script to allow users to sign up to have different features. Does it make sense to write it myself (like from this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL))

So that i create a login.php, signup.php and specific sites where i query if the user is logged in and so on..

Or is this a bad practice and there is a better way to implement this in wordpress anyway?

I am kind of a beginner in the web development so please forgive me.. thank you!

Comment: wordpress already has this

Comment: I know users can register for my wordpress site. But i don't know how to change it to the way i want it.

Comment: e.g where can i change the design of the user profile page?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/ , have you checked that out?

Comment: No. Thank you i will check it out :)